# Caching gradle output in dockerfile

Tags: docker, gradle

I've got a multistage docker file to build and run a java app.

The first section of the file creates the jar

```
FROM gradle:jdk8 as builder
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN ./gradlew build -x test
```

I then pass on the jar created to the second stage to run it.

As I'm developing this at the moment, every time I run the build, I have to sit through the ever so tedious gradle downloads and installs.

Is there a simple way to cache what gradle is doing in a volume, so I don't have to wait each time? (Impatient)

Thanks in advance

Matt